# Generate table(html table) through C# - how to generate 'th' tags?

Tags: c#

I am generating a html table dynamically through C# code. I want to be able to generate 'th' tags dynamically.

My code goes something like this

```
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
    cell1.InnerHtml = "blah";
    trow.Cells.Add(cell1);
```

I want to designate cell1 as a header row column i.e a  tag. How should i go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [constructor for HtmlTableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334411%28VS.71%29.aspx) takes in a tag name, so you can pass in "th" to create it as a table header.

```
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that it was so simple !!

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell("th");
```